# Cocoa move to parent from a subclassed instance

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface

I have a subclassed NSTextField to limit the maximum length (only 1 character). Now, once the user finishes entering this one character I would like to move the focus to the next NSSTextView. This is where I need some help. How can I tell the application "move the focus to the next field"? I suppose I need to call the parent view from the subclassed NSTextField, something like:

```
[[self parent] nextKeyView];
```

But how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `[[self window] makeFirstResponder:[self nextKeyView]]`?

Comment: Careful when / why you call this, though - if you call it any time the field's contents change, "delete" will move to the next field too. Very frustrating. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to subclass NSTextField for this, just implement the text delegate method `-textDidChange:`